# How do Jehovah's Witness view divorce?

Tags: marriage, jehovahs-witnesses, divorce

My husband is a disfellowshipped Jehovah's Witness and he has filed for a divorce.

What is the Jehovah's Witness belief about divorce and the responsibility of the husband to a non JW wife?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE! If you haven't already, please check out the [about] page.

Comment: @Rose well done phrasing a personal situation in a manner that elicits a doctrinal response. To be clear we actively discourage folks from asking for personal advice, however this is a case where the question phrasing is clearly looking for a canonical doctrinal answer. Again well done.

Comment: Your husband is no longer one of Jehovah’s Witnesses. His divorcing you on grounds other than adultery would in and of itself be evidence of that fact.

Answer (score 2):

Jehovah's Witnesses believe adultery is the only appropriate reason for divorce.

> "You have heard the law that says, 'A man can divorce his wife by merely giving her a written notice of divorce.'
>
> But I say that a man who divorces his wife, unless she has been unfaithful, causes her to commit adultery. And anyone who marries a divorced woman also commits adultery.
>
> *Matthew 5:31-32*

You stated you had not committed adultrey (before @AffableGeek removed that). Thus, Jehovah's Witnesses would say the divorce is unjustified. This can be grounds disciplinary actions (though it appears your husband has already undergone that).

This is true regardless of the spouse's faith.

If the spouse actively prevents the other from following God, or is abusive, divorce is somewhat acceptable. But in this case, the person may not remarry while the spouse is alive, or else they are guilty of adultery. It is more of a separation than a divorce.